# Entityframework disable autoincrement on purpose

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am writing application which will replace old app so on first steps, unfortunately, i must synchronize data

My class look like that

```
  public class Program
    {
        [Key]
        public int ProgramIndex { get; set; }

        public string ProgramName { get; set; }
        public string EnglishName { get; set; }
        public string ExtraData { get; set; }
    }
```

I am using sqlite for this project which allow to specify ProgramIndex or it will generate for me.

But if i try to insert with entityframework and specifying index it will fail.
I can fix that using by adding attribute to index properties

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
```

But the problem is that i need to disable autoincrement only when i am synchronizing data.

So my question is is this there any way to set DatabaseGeneratedOption.None on fly?

Comment: Actually you can set `ProgramIndex` from type `int` to `string`. That will remove the auto-increment.

Comment: @ShawnYan the problem is that i need it to be a autoincrement, only in some cases i need to switch it off...

Comment: Create a dedicated context class + class model for that task.

Comment: @GertArnold yes but it will be full copy so i dont like that idea

Comment: @GertArnold but also what i thought is to have inherited classes such as programWithIdentity, ProgramWithout identity

Comment: Ah I see, sry I didn't help. @GertArnold solution seems plausible though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way for me to do is to extend from my db context

```
 public class NoTrackingFlymarkOfflineContext : FlymarkOfflineContext
    {
        public NoTrackingFlymarkOfflineContext() : base("FlymarkOfflineContext")
        {
            Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
            Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Viddil>()
                .Property(p => p.ViddilIndex)
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
        }
    }
```

Idea is following, that for synchronization i am using different context, to speed up, and actually here overriding modelcreation is the best what i can do, so as sinse i am using NoTrackingFlymarkOfflineContext i am responsible for indexes and EntityState