# Entity Framework Core - how to programmability turn off auto increment?

Tags: c#, csv, entity-framework-core

If you add DataAnnotations "Key" a new key will be created when you execute "SaveChanges".  But if you wanted to bootstrap records into your database, how do you turn off the auto-generate a key feature?

```
public class Item 
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37939619/entityframework-disable-autoincrement-on-purpose

Comment: It's a database feature. EF can't turn it off. You have to use SQL to enable IDENTITY_INSERT. There are enough examples of that here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)] annotation on Id field

```
public class Item 
{
    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Required]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```